# Image not centered using patternImage in Swift

Tags: swift, uiimage, uilabel

In my app I display a background image on a UILabel using patternImage like so:

```
self.boxBackground = UIImage(named: "emptyBox")
self.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: boxBackground)
```

The UILabel is a custom class so this is set in the init method and boxBackground is the UIImage I'm using. The image is the exact dimensions of the custom UILabel (40x46).

This was working fine with the image displaying centered until recently when Xcode updated (Swift 5). Now it tiles slightly above and to the left so the image looks like it has been moved 5 points diagonally up to the left. The weird thing is that if there is text in the UILabel it displays correctly, as soon as the text is removed it goes back to the off-centered/tiled look.

Am I doing something wrong here or is this a bug?

Comment: Can you explain why you are using a pattern image color? What is the goal here?

Comment: @matt Hi Matt, it’s part of a game and I display an image of a cartoon box as the background for the UILabel. Depending on what’s in the label the cartoon box changes color (but dimensions remain the same). There are multiple of these labels on the screen at any one time.

Comment: That doesn’t explain why you need a pattern color in the story. A box and a label doesn’t suggest pattern color to me.

Comment: @matt Not sure what you’re looking for? I’m just after a way to display an image instead of a color for the background of a UILabel. The patternImage function was working fine and meeting my needs until it started behaving differently after the update. If there is a better method to use to display an image then I’m happy to hear it, I did a fair bit of googling and every article pointed towards patternImage. Cheers

Comment: I don't know about what articles say. I've been programming iOS since iOS 3.2 and I've never used a pattern image color in all that time. If I were doing this, I'd display the image behind the label.

Comment: Basically I feel like all this time you’ve been relying on a misuse of a feature. I don’t know why you’re seeing this odd shift in the phase of the pattern but never in a million years did Apple expect someone to use a pattern as a label background color and for a normal color it’s not an issue. So instead of living on the edge I’d suggest you just do the easy obvious thing and show the image in an image view and the text in a label as one would normally do.

Comment: @matt hmm not sure what Apple intended, the documentation on it isn’t exactly lengthy. I followed the accepted answer on another question posted here and since it worked I thought nothing of it. I was originally going to implement as you suggested but then found a way that felt superior as it meant less views to manage. If there isn’t a fix I will either implement it in an additional view or use a custom UIButton which comes with a background image property.

Comment: Well if you really want fewer views you could add a layer to the label and draw the image into that label. The point is, a drawing is a drawing, not a background color.